# Understanding a number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Firstly I hope this question is formed well enough for you. I am very much new to mathematics and this Stack site, you will have to excuse any incorrect terms. I appreciate your patience.

Given a number of nodes on a line, I am calculating the maximum equidistant  points it may have across it.

As a criteria, the first and last point must be populated. So for example a line containing 7 points can have 4 occupied spaces if they are to be evenly spaced.

```
* * * *
•••••••
```

I have been studying the sequence which has emerged and it has left me confused, mostly unable to identify a name or any material so I may study further.

As far as I can tell you can calculate an odd numbers maximum with `(n+1)/2`

I am however struggling to reliably calculate the same for a given even number.

The sequence I have is (the bottom number is my calculated maximum)

```
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
2,3,2,4,2,5,4 ,6 ,2 ,7 ,2 ,8 ,6 ,9 ,2 ,10,2 ,11,8 ,12,2 ,13,6 ,14,10
```

I am keen to learn more and understand this set of numbers, I hope someone can lend me some wisdom.

Comment: In your example the nodes are not equally spaced. Is the second row (after the final 28 of the first row) meant as a solution for the row above? Are repeated numbers OK in a solution, and what does "equally spaced" mean for a solution?

Comment: Sorry, that is confusing. So in the number sequence the top row relates to the bottom row in the bullet/star example. Equally spaced refers to the physical location on the line, so for the 7/4 case it means for 7 points I can place 4 markers on the line with equal distance between them. I'm hoping that makes sense!

Comment: Oh I got that now. So for the odd $n$ in top row it's $(n+1)/2$ in the bottom row as the max of equally spaced points, with first and last spots filled and at least one space between any two adjacent filled spots. Is that the meaning?

Comment: Absolutely right, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill spots $1$ and $n$ and are looking for the most spots you can fill in between that are evenly spaced.  Note that you have $n-1$ spaces to divide evenly, so you want to factor $n-1$.  If $n$ is odd, $n-1$ will have a factor $2$ so you can fill every other spot, giving a total of $\frac {n+1}2$ spots as you have found.  You want the smallest factor of $n-1$ so you put the spots as close together as possible.  In your table, you can see that all the even numbers that are one more that a prime have only two spots because the prime cannot be divided.  If $m$ is the smallest factor of $n-1$ the number of spots is $\frac {n-1}m + 1$ where the $+1$ comes because you have both ends like [fenceposts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

Comment: That was very easy to understand and answered my question perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For even $n$ you seek the arithmetic progression with the smallest difference $d>1$ such that there is $k$ for which $1+kd=n.$ Here the last equation is so spot $n$ gets filled, and $d>1$ is so there are definitely some space between the filled positions. Then the number is $k+1$ for your problem.

Example $n=10.$ Then $n-1=9=3\cdot 3$ so here the least $d>1$ is $3$ and you get $3+1=4$ points. Note the $3$ used in the formula $k+1$ is $(n-1)/d$ in general.

The resulting thing for even $n$ is erratic, since then the least factor exceeding $1$ of $n-1$ is also erratic. Consider e.g. when $n-1$ is a prime.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, both of these answers were insightful and useful.